# WPF - Combobox Grouping with binding to observableCollection

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, combobox

Not sure why there is so litle about this to find. I've tried everything I could find but I still do not get my combobox to show the item.

So far, it show the group header but nothing inside. As soon as I click on the drop down, it fill my observableCollection in the code, create the view and bind it to the itemsource.

Also, when I click on it, the default item become the first one that I can see very well. However, the list is still empty looking. If I click next to it and hit the keyboard arrow (left and right), it scroll through items so everything is clearly there but just not showing.

I'd appreciate any help. I have a feeling it's going to be something stupid. :)

Here's my XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ExportDropDown" 
            DropDownOpened="GetAllProcessesAndObjects" 
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="White" Padding="3"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding POI_processName}" Foreground="White"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

VB.NET

```
Sub GetAllProcessesAndObjects()
    Try
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection
        Dim DatabaseName As String = "ImageRecognition"
        conn.ConnectionString = String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User Id={2};Password={3}", General_VM.DB_DBdataSource, DatabaseName, General_VM.DB_DBusername, General_VM.DB_DBpassword)


        Dim Query As New SqlCommand(
                String.Format("SELECT    [processid]
                                        ,[ProcessType]
                                        ,[name]
                                    FROM [Development].[dbo].[BPAProcess];"),
        conn)

        Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter(Query)

        conn.Open()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        sda.Fill(dt)

        Dim opList As New ObservableCollection(Of ProcessObjectItem)
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim newItem As New ProcessObjectItem
            newItem.POI_uid = row("processid")
            newItem.POI_processType = row("ProcessType")
            newItem.POI_processName = row("name")
            opList.Add(newItem)
        Next

        CR_VM.CR_processCollection = opList

        Dim processView As ICollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(CR_VM.CR_processCollection)

        If processView IsNot Nothing And processView.CanGroup = True Then
            processView.GroupDescriptions.Clear()
            processView.GroupDescriptions.Add(New PropertyGroupDescription("POI_processType"))
        End If
        processView.Refresh()

        ExportDropDown.ItemsSource = processView
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

In my viewModel(Which is CR_VM), the Collection:

```
Private processCollection As ObservableCollection(Of ProcessObjectItem) = New ObservableCollection(Of ProcessObjectItem)
Public Property CR_processCollection() As ObservableCollection(Of ProcessObjectItem)
    Get
        Return processCollection
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of ProcessObjectItem))
        processCollection = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("CR_processCollection")
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Is it because your `Foreground="White"` for your `TextBlock`? Try `Foreground="Black"`

Comment: Background is black. Thats why. :)

Comment: @Nik Finally, you made me think about something I hadn't tried. I remove the style I had going on and with the default style... It's all there so there is something in my template hidding everything. Thanks for pointing it out even if it wasn't exactly that. You triggered it. :)

Comment: Nice! `Foreground="White"` stuck out like a sore thumb `+` your description of the issue, totally sounded like something of the sort. I was about 50% sure it was exactly that lol.

Comment: @Nik I actually found the real issue. In the template example that Microsoft provide, the Stackpanel they use in the ScrollViewer does not work with grouping. You need to use "ItemsPresenter" for the item to show up.